# How to disable Source Control Providers in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I disable the new "Source Control Providers" feature in vscode?

[image].

I just want the old simple git view, because this isn't very useful for me.

Comment: Another reason you might (temporarily) wish to disable this is for directories or workspaces which are on a network share (such as an SSHFS FUSE) and you don't want to flood the remote server (and you can't use VS Code's remote integration)

Answer (score 58):

From **File** menu select **preferences** ---> **settings**
or simply press `ctrl + ,`

just notice in the new versions of visual studio code, the settings window is displayed as normal options not as json file, like what I attached here and I don't know if there is a way to get back the settings as json file.

[image: disable git]

Comment: it disable the git extensions itself, its correct answer for the questions, but not everyone want to do this.

Comment: It is ok. it is just a concept

Comment: It worked for me, as I only need to disable git for one folder I added to workspace.  Thank you.

Comment: Finally. A Good answer

Answer (score 20):

I think this is solution, **vscode** -> **preferences** -> **settings** :

```
"git.autoRepositoryDetection": false
```

Comment: This does not work (anymore) for completely dissabling git version control in the explorer. (Version: 1.44.2)

Comment: I am also on 1.44.2 and this seems to be working for me.

Comment: vscode team AGAIN changed settings in 2022 feb and there is NO WAY TO HAVE 1 REPO... I am going back to version 1.54 of ARM macos vscode for M1 :/

Answer (score 4):

> // Controls whether to always show the Source Control Provider
>   section.

```
 "scm.alwaysShowProviders": false,
```

`False` is the default, make sure that wasn't set to `true` in your settings.

Answer (score 1):

just Click-Right on it and Click on **"Hide Source Control"** It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Steps: File > Preferences > Settings
Then Search and Change it to "false".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djGEk.png)